# Excel Pivot Table - Extract List of Pivot Items and Concatenate with semi-colon

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have data in pivot table as represented in the image. My requirement is to extract item values( Column B and C) for each of the field list (Column A). Store these values to string and separate multiple values in Col C by semi-colon(;):

Eg: For every HOD Field > i.e. MGR1 > extract H12345 from Col B(HOD ID field), and R12345; R12346 from Col C(REP ID Field) and save these values to strings to be used later in the code.

and so forth with MGR2, MGR3 etc...

I tried something like this, but not sure how to save the values to a string, sorry new to vb:

```
Sub PivotTabletest()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Dim rng3 As Range


Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("HOD View").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set rng1 = PvtTbl.PivotFields("REP ID").DataRange
Set rng2 = PvtTbl.PivotFields("HOD").PivotItems("MGR1").DataRange.EntireRow ' MGR1 should be picked dynamically instead

Set rng3 = Intersect(rng1, rng2)  

'Intersect(rng1, rng2).Interior.Color = vbYellow 'color coding works!



 For Each Cell In rng3
    Debug.Print Cell.Value

    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Updated code, able to print values for Col3, but need to be able to make "PivotItems("MGR1")" dynamic(not hard coded)

[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oMIy.png)

Comment: Lots of thoughts - what have you tried?  e.g. `For Each PivotItem In PivotField.PivotItems`, and either "String =  String & ";" & PivotItem.Value" or an array and the [`Join` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)?

Comment: Thanks Chronocidal for response, I did try "For Each PivotItem.." and Intersect function, but wasn't sure how to capture and save to strings. updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

This Function will return an array with a row for each HOD

```
Function PivotTableTest() AS Variant
    Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable, DataRng As Range, WorkingRow AS Range
    Dim Output() As String, ItemNumber AS Long

    Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("HOD View").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    Set DataRng = PvtTbl.DataBodyRange

    'Resize the array, with a row for every entry in HOD ID
    Redim Output(0 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(PvtTbl.TableRange1.Columns(2)), 0 to 2)

    ItemNumber = 0

    'Loop down the rows
    For Each WorkingRow In DataRng.Rows
            'HOD in the first column
            If Len(WorkingRow.Cells(1,1).Offset(0,-2).Value) > 0 Then Output(ItemNumber, 0) = WorkingRow.Cells(1,1).Offset(0,-2).Value

            'HOD ID in the second column
            If Len(WorkingRow.Cells(1,1).Offset(0,-1).Value) > 0 Then Output(ItemNumber, 1) = WorkingRow.Cells(1,1).Offset(0,-1).Value

            'REP ID in the third column
            If Len(WorkingRow.Cells(1,1).Value) > 0 Then
                    Output(ItemNumber, 2) = Output(ItemNumber, 2) & IIF(Len(Output(ItemNumber, 2))>0,";","") & WorkingRow.Cells(1,1).Value
            Else
                    'Next Row
                    ItemNumber = ItemNumber+1
            End If

    Next WorkingRow

    'Remove any unused Rows from the array
    If ItemNumber > 0 Then Redim Preserve Output(0 to ItemNumber-1, 0 to 2)

    'Assign the Array to the Function output
    PivotTableTest = Output 
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Chronocidal, getting syntax error on following line:               
 Output(ItemNumber, 2) = Output(ItemNumber, 2) & IIF(Len(Output(ItemNumber, 2)>0,";","") & WorkingRow.Cells(1,1).Value

Comment: Sorry, missed a close-bracket for the `Len` (`Len(Output(ItemNumber, 2))>0`) - added now

Comment: Thanks Chronocial, but I am not able to call the function or print any values? Can you please give an example to print one of the values?

Comment: The function will return a 2D Array, so you can print values like this `Dim SomeArray As Variant: SomeArray = PivotTableTest: Debug.Print SomeArray(0, 0) & " | " & SomeArray(0, 1) & " | " & SomeArray(0, 2)`

Comment: Thanks! It's printing numerical values from Col D eg: |  | 5;1;32;9;18;11; ..........  Not printing values from Col A, B and C